# How to correct bad sql grammar when passing data?

Tags: sql, json, jdbc

This is my JDBC file with a the following sql query:

```
private static final String UPDATE_QUESTION = "UPDATE Quiz SET type=?, questionIndex=?, choiceNum=?, question=?, choiceA=?, choiceB=?, choiceC=?, choiceD=?, correct=?, hint=? WHERE type=? AND questionIndex=?";
```

When I try and pass some data into the query above in JSON format:

```json
{
"id": 84,
"type":"epidemics",
"questionIndex": 1,
"choiceNum":2,
"question":"updated question3",
"choiceA": "no3",
"choiceB":"yes2",
"choiceC":"no3",
"choiceD":"yes4",
"correct":"no3",
"hint":"second answer"
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

```json
 "timestamp": "2022-11-26T11:52:16.431+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE Quiz SET type=?, questionIndex=?, choiceNum=?, question=?, choiceA=?, choiceB=?, choiceC=?, choiceD=?, correct=?, hint=? WHERE (type=?) AND (questionIndex=?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 12
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong in the query?

Comment: I don't know about JDBC, but are you sure it's supposed to work like this with JSON? The question marks in the query make it looks like it's designed for ordered parameters, and not named parameters. Your JSON has 11 values but the query expects 12 parameters, and the error is also about missing 12th parameter. Though I'm not sure how it manages with this JSON. Maybe it just takes its values (in potentially arbitrary order) and discards the keys? Seems risky...

Comment: Show us how this JSON is getting bound to the prepared statement.

Comment: Please show the code that actually executes the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you need to pass a value for each `?` placeholder, *even if the same column appears more than once in the prepared statement*.  So, you need to bind the value for `questionIndex` twice.  Your Java code should look something like:

```java
String UPDATE_QUESTION = "UPDATE Quiz SET type=?, questionIndex=?, choiceNum=?, question=?, choiceA=?, choiceB=?, choiceC=?, choiceD=?, correct=?, hint=? WHERE type=? AND questionIndex=?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(UPDATE_QUESTION);
ps.setString(1, type);
ps.setInt(2, questionIndex);  // first setter for questionIndex
ps.setInt(3, choiceNum);
ps.setString(4, question); 
ps.setString(5, choiceA);
ps.setString(6, choiceB);
ps.setString(7, choiceC);
ps.setString(8, choiceD);
ps.setString(9, correct);
ps.setString(10, hint);
ps.setString(11, type);
ps.setInt(12, questionIndex);  // second setter for questionIndex

int row = ps.executeUpdate();
// rows affected
System.out.println(row);
```